# First list item in HTML list appearing slightly too high

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I was just starting to make a basic page layout when a problem I couldn't quite grasp came to me again.
Why does my page have one list box to the left higher than the others?
Any information would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
body{
background-color:#5187B9;
font-size:120%;
color:#666666;
}
li{
list-style:none;
}
#wrapper{
margin:0 auto;
width:960px;
}
.top{
width:100%;
}
.block01{
clear:both;
background-color:white;
border-radius:4px;
border:1px solid white;
}
.menu{
width:100%;
height:45px;
padding-top:5px;
background-color:#E8EFF6;
}
.menu ul{
height:40px;
margin-left:20px;
}
.menu li{
float:left;
margin-left:5px;
margin-right:5px;
padding:5px;
background-color:#8888F6;
color:#277098;
}
.block02{
clear:both;
width:100%;
color:white;
}
.block02 ul{
width:100%;
clear:both;
color:black;
}
.block02 li{
float:left;
height:300px;
width:120px;
border-radius:4px;
border:1px solid white;
background-color:white;
}
.block02 ul .list02{
margin-left:20px;
margin-right:20px;
}
.block03{
clear:both;
width:100%;
background-color:white;
padding:10px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="top">
</div>
    <div class="block01">
    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
    <li>ホーム</li>
    <li>特徴</li>
    <li>プラン</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="block02">
    <ul>
    <li class="list01"></li>
    <li class="list02"></li>
    <li class="list03"></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="block03">

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It might be because you give the .menu li a margin-left. This one keeps inheriting when you go deeper. So the ul li > ul li will had a margin of 10. The ul in that li will have 15.. But i can't be too certain though :)

Comment: which browser? as it looks ok to me http://jsfiddle.net/kbqaB/

Comment: CaptainCarl you are correct. My mistake for missing that.

I am using Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the [`clear`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/clear) property in your CSS.

> The clear property indicates which sides of an element's box(es) may not be adjacent to an earlier floating box.

Removing the `clear` property generates the result you need.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GsUfv/)

**P.S.**: I have changed height to `250px`.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Inheritance is one of those things that I have been missing lately. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

remove the `clear:both` on the `.block02 ul`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the margin-top to 0 for .block02 ul